# Facing Error While using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, parsing

I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to fetch urls, but i got an error while fetching links. Have a look at this script:

```
$result = str_get_html($result);
foreach($result->find('a') as $element)
$result = str_get_html($result);
$result = str_replace('http://', '', $result);
foreach($result->find('a') as $elementa)
echo $element->href;
echo $elementa->href;
```

Here I want to fetch all links for twice, first time urls in `$element->href` will fetch links starting with `http://` and in `$elementa->href` will fetch links without `http://`.

But this shows only a blank page. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = str_get_html($result);
$arrWithPrefix = array();
$arrWithoutPrefix = array();
foreach ($result->find('a') as $link) {
    $arrWithPrefix[] = $link->href;
    $arrWithoutPrefix[] = str_replace('http://', '', $link->href);
}
var_dump($arrWithPrefix);
var_dump($arrWithoutPrefix);
```

Not tested, see if it is any good :)

Comment: Do you want the entire `<A>` tag for each element ?

Comment: Could you please edit your question with a sample input HTML and the unexpected output from the above script ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. please take some time visiting here http://codepad.org/TWIYdkX3 and look what to do to do the exact i want to do.. Thanks again

Comment: Skimming, I saw that you're pasting the component source code in your script (I presume for running the app on codepad). Try this: in the extracted folder for the zip file you downloaded from their website, copy and paste [this](http://codepad.org/CyUGT6EH) to a `test.php` file inside the folder `app`. Notice that it refers to the php file in the folder above it, so be certain that it is there. Try this and then tell us what happens. **Edit: fixed source.

Comment: thanks, but i ama php learner so cant understand why  it showing lots of texts like `} array(16) { [0]=> string(161) "` .... how to make it clean .Thanks

Comment: Great! Read about the [var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump) function. It dumps the variables to show their content. The idea is: now you have 2 arrays, with the links, and can read their content as you want. You can erase the `var_dump` calls and echo the array contents or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this code it will set the http:// sitename to the link and will return all links with one link

```
foreach ($html->find('a') as $e) {
   $cssHrefs = $e -> href;
   preg_match_all('~' . SITE_NAME . '~is', $cssHrefs, $match);
   if (count($match[0]) == 0) {
        $loadedHrefs[] = SITE_NAME . $cssHrefs;
   } else {
        $loadedHrefs[] = $cssHrefs;
}
var_dump($loadedHrefs);
```

Answer (score 0):

u may try this as well

```
$result = str_get_html($result);
foreach($result->find('a') as $element){
$result = str_get_html($result);
$result = str_replace('http://', '', $result);
}
foreach($result->find('a') as $elementa){
echo $element->href;
echo $elementa->href;
}
```